# open a file in PHP CLI

Tags: php, file-permissions, command-line-interface

The file was created by apache using mkdir() and fopen() etc..

How do i let my php CLI program be allowed to read that file that apache (that is what it says the user is) created so i dont get this error:

`Warning: file_get_contents(./sessions/nl2larsjl6n3315mesghmspts7.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/cli.php on line 58`

in the cli this my code for getting the file:

```
$alert = file_get_contents('./sessions/'.$sessionID.'.txt');
```

Comment: i changed it to chmod 0777 still get the same error on cli

Comment: chmod() http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php

Comment: i did that i used it. see my comment above

Comment: 1. the issue is the path your giving it, its wrong, 2. why would you ever want to directly access a session temp file?

Comment: ignore that it says session. i named the folder that way stupidly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: 
when you create it, you should run `chmod(0777)` on it.

Long answer: 
`chmod(0777)` means "world readable and writable, and not actually recommended. Checkout http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_permissions, http://www.linuxforums.org/articles/file-permissions_94.html for a complete explanation on these numbers.
Basically if you need it to be writable by a user, and readable by any user, do a `chmod(0644)`

---

EDit: i was quick to wrinte an answer... without reading the question carefully.

You seem to try and open the file from a different directory than the folder where you created it.
Try and see the result on `echo getpwd()` in the CLI script and then in the script running under www. I bet you will see different locations.
When executing CLI scripts you should either do a `chdir()` before running the command or use absolute paths at all times for the files you access.
I personally prefer the `chdir()` method.

Comment: thank you, that was the issue. i forgot that in CLI the file runs from whereever you run it so '/session' might not be correct :-)